# React Native: Platform specific code in package.json

Tags: android, ios, react-native, expo

I want to use expo 32 for iOS, but expo 31 for Android. Like so:

```
"expo": Platform.OS === 'ios' ? "^32.0.0" : "^31.0.4"
```

What would be a good way to do that in a json file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know this feature doesn't exist. They do have an os specifier in docs which may help to some degree but doesn't solve the exact problem you're having.

os specifier: https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#os

There is also an external npm package with a similar feature here:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-platform-dependencies

Finally, I was also able to find this previous post with some suggestions that may be of use to you, one of the answers someone recommended install scripts.

[npm package.json OS specific dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15176082/npm-package-json-os-specific-dependency)