# Make nodejs server platform dependent

Tags: node.js

Can we make a nodejs server platform dependent. Like it must only run on linux system with a specific version which can't be catched by other developer easily.

Comment: In others terms: to forbid other OS than Linux ??

Comment: Look at [npm package.json OS specific dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26069595/10489562)

Comment: You can do all kinds of OS detection and break the program itself on non-Linux platforms, but Node.js apps can be easily analyzed and reverse engineered, so all such attempts won't stop your users from running it on other platforms if they know the way out.