# Installing sharp package for multiple platforms

Tags: node.js, installation, cross-platform, package.json

I am trying to install the `sharp` npm package, but my project currently runs on Windows and Linux platforms. Whenever I install the base package only, I get an entry like the following in my package.json:

```
"sharp": "^0.33.1"
```

When using the module, the following error occurs:

```
Error: Could not load the "sharp" module using the [win32-x64|linux-x64] runtime
Possible solutions: ...
```

Of the possible solutions mentioned, only installing the native package (e.g. @img/sharp-linux-x64) works. But this leads to the issue, that the package.json now only works on the specific platform, as (obviously) other platforms cannot install the native package of the foreign platform.

I already tried to manually adapt the package.json using `optionalDependencies` key mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15176082/npm-package-json-os-specific-dependency), but simply calling `npm install` doesn't install any of them.

Do I have to create a special solution, like a manual install script? I try to avoid this, as I have to remember the special handling just for this project and other users need to learn about it as well.

Is there a way to install the correct platform-dependent package by simply using `npm install`?

Comment: Are you having problems because you are running your code on a windows device but you deploy your code/server on a service such as heroku/render.com?

Comment: Almost. I am testing and developing on Windows, and deploying the code to a Ubuntu server (VM).

Comment: @njho Unfortunately not. I am currently using another package which does not have native dependencies. But it is very slow compared to sharp.

Comment: @walderich It's a bug on npm that isn't fixed yet, a solution I use for now (because I really need to use sharp) is to uninstall the sharp @img/sharp-win32-x64 before I commit to github and for it to work on heroku which I use to host my server, I actually set this in scripts in package.json:
"start": "npm i @img/sharp-linux-x64 && node index"
not the ideal solution because its so annoying but its fine for the time being

Answer (score 1):

I use "optionalDependencies" in package.json to solve it. Add the following in your package.json

```js
{
  ...,
  "dependencies": {
    ...,
    "sharp": "^0.32.6"
  },
  "optionalDependencies": {
    "@img/sharp-win32-x64": "^0.33.2",
    "@img/sharp-linux-arm": "^0.33.2"
  }
}
```

When running "npm install" in Windows environment, @img/sharp-linux-arm will NOT be able to install and thus skipped. Similarly, when running "npm install" in Linux environment, this time "@img/sharp-win32-x64" will be skipped.

Comment: I already tried using "optionalDependencies" for this. Unfortunately none of the packages is installed when running "npm i". Do I need another argument for trying to install optional dependency packages?

Comment: No, you don't need to. Try remove the entire node_modules and package-lock.json and "npm install" again. Then, try it out although the @img folder is empty in node_modules, and see what error it gives.